# Is there a way to make RFT scripts runnable in java eclipse?

Tags: java, rft

I am trying to move my RFT java files to eclipse and import all the required jar files into eclipse.. will this run my RFT script the way it does when i run it in RFT environment for testing?

Pls help.
Harika

Comment: What's an RFT file in this context?

Comment: RFT script , i have taken the java file and placed in eclipse and took all the required jars for the same.. is it possible to integrate?

Comment: Still no clue about what is an RFT script :-) Any links what it stands for? Which language/tool generates it?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? RFT (Rational Functional Tester) IDE **is** Eclipse.

Comment: I think the poster wants to point a clean copy of Eclipse at the RFT JARs, and run the scripts on this new copy of Eclipse. I'm not sure if it will work

Answer (score 2):

No it won't. RFT is a distribution of Eclipse with some proprietary bits. You can't run your RFT tests outside the context of RFT.

Comment: +1, agree, especially that it is possible, but not efficient since the "proprietary bits" are mostly undocumented and probably version-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in another way which is integrate your project from Eclipse into RFT.